# T-SQL ROW_NUMBER() Up a creek without a paddle

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I am trying to select the previous status of a claim from transaction data. I have used the code below

```
DECLARE @InputDate DATE = '2018-10-01'  
DECLARE @DateOne   DATE = DATEADD(M, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @InputDate), 0))    
DECLARE @DateTwo   DATE = DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @InputDate), 0))

SELECT
    [Claim Number], [Partner], [Scheme],
    [Claim Status], [Trans ID],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Claim Number], [Claim Status] ORDER BY [Claim Number], [Trans ID] DESC) AS Row#
FROM
    (SELECT
         dc.ClaimNumber        as [Claim Number],
         dbp.BusinessPartner   as [Partner],
         ds.Scheme             as [Scheme],
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dc.NotificationDate, 103) as [Notification Date],
         CASE 
            WHEN LEN(dcs.[ClaimStatus]) < 1 
               THEN NULL
               ELSE 
                  CASE WHEN dcs.[ClaimStatus] = 'Inactive' 
                            AND dtuat.UserFullName = 'Rodger Recovery' 
                          THEN 'Recovery' 
                          ELSE dcs.[ClaimStatus] 
                  END
         END as [Claim Status],
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Library.ufConvertIntToDate(ftcs.TransactionDimDateId), 121)     as [Transaction Date],
         ftcs.TransactionDimDateId    as [Trans ID] 
     FROM   
         TravelClaim.uvDimClaimA1R2V1 dc 
     JOIN
         TravelClaim.uvFactTravelClaimStatusA1R2V2 ftcs ON dc.DimClaimId =ftcs.DimClaimId
     JOIN 
         TravelClaim.uvDimClaimStatusA1R2V2 dcs ON ftcs.DimClaimStatusId = dcs.DimClaimStatusId
     JOIN 
         TravelClaim.uvDimBusinessPartnerA1R2V1 dbp ON ftcs.DimBusinessPartnerId = dbp.DimBusinessPartnerId
     JOIN 
         TravelClaim.uvDimSchemeA1R2V1 ds ON ftcs.DimSchemeId = ds.DimSchemeId
     JOIN 
         TravelClaim.uvDimTeamUserA2R2V1 dtuat ON ftcs.AccessedByDimTeamUserId = dtuat.DimTeamUserId
     WHERE
         dcs.ClaimStatus NOT LIKE 'Query'
         AND dc.ClaimNumber NOT LIKE 'Unknown') AS a
 WHERE
     [Transaction Date] >= @DateOne 
     AND [Transaction Date] <= @DateTwo 
     AND [claim number] = 'abc/1234567' 
 ORDER BY 
     [claim number], [Trans ID]desc
```

This returns the following result:

```
Claim Number Partner    Scheme          Claim Status Trans ID   Row#
---------------------------------------------------------------------
abc/1234567 something   something else  Settled      20180922   1
abc/1234567 something   something else  Settled      20180921   2
abc/1234567 something   something else  Settled      20180917   3
abc/1234567 something   something else  Open         20180914   1
abc/1234567 something   something else  Settled      20180912   4
abc/1234567 something   something else  Settled      20180905   5
abc/1234567 something   something else  Settled      20180904   6
```

I need to select each time the status has changed which would be

```
Claim Number Partner    Scheme          Claim Status    Trans ID    Row#
------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc/1234567 something   something else  Settled         20180922    1
abc/1234567 something   something else  Open            20180914    1
abc/1234567 something   something else  Settled         20180912    4
```

So the idea was to select the rows where row# = 1 however this would not give me the correct result as I would be missing the settled to open change row# 4

If this had worked I intended to use row_number again and select all the rows with row# = 2 then join this back to my main data giving me a previous status column and if necessary =3 etc in additional columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use lag and test for null or <> current

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Using the `LAG` or `LEAD` functions as suggested in the comments would probably better if your version of SQL supports it. I learned something new today!

---

Here's how I would do it.  Of course, you can change the name of `cte` to whatever you would like, and you will need to fill in the table joins and column selects, but this is the bones of the concept.

```
;with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by [Claim Number] order by [Claim Number],[Trans ID] as rowNum
    from ... put your tables here
)
select a.*
from cte a
left join cte b
    on a.rowNum = b.rowNum + 1
where a.[Claim Status] != b.[Claim Status]
```